# Resolve exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for Intellij Idea, where the main idea is to get the structure of a Kotlin class as: properties, methods, etc.
In my **plugin.xml** I added the following line `<depends>org.jetbrains.kotlin</depends>`

And as a library to access the class `KtVisitor` I added to gradle the following library:
`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler:1.2.30`

Everything is compiling with exception, that when I'm running the code and listen to the action, I'm getting the following error:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile cannot be cast to com.intellij.psi.PsiFile`

Mine class responsible for listening to the action is following:

```
class ConvertAction: AnAction(), DumbAware {
override fun actionPerformed(event: AnActionEvent?) {
    val psiFile = event?.getData(PlatformDataKeys.PSI_FILE)
    val s = true
}}
```

Appreciate any help how to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClassCastException` happens because IDEA loads two copies of the Kotlin plugin classes, one from the actual Kotlin plugin and another from the `kotlin-compiler.jar` that you're providing. The correct way to add the plugin dependency is to add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
intellij {
    plugins 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Maybe jus to make a point about creating the plugin project using **Gradle** instead of **DevKit**. By the way, do you know a solution for **DevKit**?

Comment: For other who can't resolve the issue by using the line above, try to use something like that **org.jetbrains.kotlin:1.2.21-release-IJ2017.3-1@** Thank you @yole for your help!

Comment: Does this work for Android Studio too?