# KtFile cannot be cast to KtFile: Problem with Kotlin PSI while plugin development

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin

Please, help me identify my mistake. I'm developing the custom plugin for Android Studio and while trying to process the Kotlin file, received from the Action I receive the following error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile cannot be cast to class org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile (org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @6bf6bf87; org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @62ccc687) at com.ordinarythinker.jcat.ProcessKtFileAction.actionPerformed(ProcessKtFileAction.kt:24)`

The exception occurs in the indicated line:

```
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.CommonDataKeys
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project
import com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile
import com.intellij.psi.PsiElement
import com.intellij.psi.PsiElementVisitor
import com.intellij.psi.PsiFile
import com.intellij.psi.PsiManager
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtNamedFunction

class ProcessKtFileAction : AnAction() {
    override fun actionPerformed(e: AnActionEvent) {
        val project: Project = e.project ?: return
        val file: VirtualFile? = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE)

        if (file != null && file.isValid) {
            val psiFile: PsiFile? = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.PSI_FILE)

            try {
                val ktFile = psiFile as KtFile // exception is thrown here
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
    // some other code
}
```

The problem is in different loaders of the class and, as the result, in impossibility to convert it to the `KtFile` type, though debugger shows that the PsiFile I received from action **is** `KtFile`.

TLDR: if you wish to reproduce the error, you can use my repository on [github](https://github.com/ordinarythinker/jCat)

I followed instructions from [Intellij docs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/creating-plugin-project.html) and from [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006794080-Cannot-Cast-PsiElement-to-KtClass).

Here is my build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
   id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.16.0"
   id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.21"
}
group = "com.ordinarythinker"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
   implementation(kotlin("compiler-embeddable", "1.9.21"))
   implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
}
apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.intellij")
apply(plugin = "kotlin")
intellij {
   version.set("2022.3.1")
   type.set("IC")
   plugins.set(listOf("android", "Kotlin"))
}
tasks {
   withType<JavaCompile> {
       sourceCompatibility = "17"
       targetCompatibility = "17"
   }
   withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
       kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
   }
   runIde {
       ideDir.set(file("C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio2"))
   }
   patchPluginXml {
       sinceBuild.set("223")
       untilBuild.set("241.*")
   }
   signPlugin {
       certificateChain.set(System.getenv("CERTIFICATE_CHAIN"))
       privateKey.set(System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))
       password.set(System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD"))
   }
   publishPlugin {
       token.set(System.getenv("PUBLISH_TOKEN"))
   }
}
```

To avoid clash in stblib versions, according to [docs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/using-kotlin.html#kotlin-standard-library), I excluded stdlib, provided by Intellij plugin by default, in my `gradle.properties` file:

```
kotlin.stdlib.default.dependency = false
```

I also indicated that my plugin relies on the `org.jetbrains.kotlin` by adding `<depends>org.jetbrains.kotlin</depends>` to `plugin.xml`:

```
<idea-plugin>
    <id>com.ordinarythinker.jCat</id>

    <name>jCat</name>

    <vendor email="" url="https://github.com/ordinarythinker">Andrii D.</vendor>

    <description><![CDATA[
    JCat is a plugin for automated tests generation for Composable functions<br>
    <em>Currently is underway the development</em>
  ]]></description>

    <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>

    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    </extensions>

    <actions>
        <action
                id="ProcessKtFileAction"
                class="com.ordinarythinker.jcat.ProcessKtFileAction"
                text="Generate Test"
                description="Generate test">
            <add-to-group group-id="EditorPopupMenu" anchor="last"/>
        </action>
    </actions>

    <depends>org.jetbrains.kotlin</depends>
</idea-plugin>
```

I tried adding `org.jetbrains.kotlin` to `plugin` in `intellij` block as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429166/resolve-exception-java-lang-classcastexception-org-jetbrains-kotlin-psi-ktfile), but the problem remains. And the actions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272198/cannot-cast-psielement-to-ktclass-intellij) don't help either.

Can anyone point me at what am I missing? Thanks in advance for any help